# Please how can I solve this error on VS Code React Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

Please what does this error mean:

`errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]`

I get the error anytime I run NPM START in my VSCode React Project.

It is a fresh installation of create-react-app. It is supposed to start at first run. Kindly help look into the Package.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the full error from vscode console:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: More information would help.

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, have you set your environment variable?

Comment: I'm on Windows10

Comment: I already added nodejs path on environment variable. What else should I add?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a new react project you are probably missing the node_modules folder, which means you didn't install the dependencies needed for the project. To do so, run 'npm install'. This should install all the dependencies you need. After this, you are going to be able to run npm start. If this does not help, please provide the package.json file at the root folder of your project so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: It's a fresh installation of create-react-app. I have edited the post with package.json file

Comment: did you run npm install?

Comment: Yes. I run npm install

Comment: When you run npm start you probably get a longer error. Could you provide me with the complete error, please?

Answer (score 0):

I added `C:\Windows\System32` to PATH in environment variable. It worked